# Url mod_rewrite not working

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I created two pages

alice.php and bob.php

### code for alice.php

```
<?php
echo "This is alice page";
?>

<form name="sdlflks" method="get" action="bob.php">
<input type="text" name="t1">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

### code for bob.php

```
<?php
echo "This is bob page";
echo "<br>" . $_GET['t1'];
?>
```

I typed on alice page as helloworld, then it redirects to bob.php in this url format
    http://localhost/test1/bob.php?t1=helloworld&submit=Submit

rather i would like to appear as

```
http://localhost/test1/bob.php/helloworld
```

or

```
http://localhost/test1/bob/helloworld
```

I googled and some articles, answer over here but could not get this one.

And also created a .htacces.conf in the same directory as "test1"

In .htaccess.conf

i added this experssion for mod_rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ bob.php?t1=$1&submit=$2 [L]
```

Can any let me know, who i achieve this.
And where should i add this expression in which line of code or in which module do i need to put this.

Answer (score 1):

By only using mod_rewrite you'll only get as far as:

```
http://localhost/test1/bob?t1=helloworld&submit=Submit
```

That's because the HTML form submission happens from the browser and by default it appends the GET parameters as pairs, separated by ampersand.

If you really need the form submittion to end up at:

```
http://localhost/test1/bob/helloworld
```

there are 2 solutions:

- submit using javascript. Which means that you'll capture the submit and simply send the user to the URL above
- submit normally and from your php script imediatelly do a redirect to the URL above to execute the action in the "pretty" URL

Comment: Can you let me know how to do that step by step.

Comment: Yes. Lots of people could answer that in a new question called "how to make a form submit to a clean URL".